# Layout Qt widgets in Circle, not circular widget

Tags: c++, qt

[image]

How to layout any qt widgets in circle, and the every widget can respond to click event, set different color text and color.

Comment: you can use graphics items for painting the items but about circular alignment, there is not any solution in Qt for your design.

Comment: If you use QML, a PathView might help.

Comment: There is no such layout available in Qt to match your requirement. You will need to customize your widgets and layout to meet such arrangements. However, your problem appears somewhat similar to Pie Menu. Try this [link](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq11-piemenu.html)